# Jquery How to Create two and three dimensional Array

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am new to jquery.I want to create an array like this

```
var pos=[];
 pos['div1']['left']=200;
  pos['div2']['left']=400;
  pos['div3']['left']=600;
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is attempting to use an array like an associative array.

When using the syntax `pos['div1']['left']` the interpreter expects an object possessing a div1 property, which has a left property.  This is completely different than a normal array which strictly uses whole numbers for indexes.  A normal array does not allow `Strings` to be used to access elements of the array.

Associative arrays or objects on the other hand provide for this flexibility.  They also allow for objects to be nested within objects.  I believe this data structure would suite your needs better:

```
//Initial Object
var pos={};
//assign an object with a left property to the property div1 on the pos object
pos.div1 = {left:200};
pos.div2 = {left:400};
pos.div3 = {left:600};

alert(pos.div1.left);

//This data structure could be declared as one object literal upfront
var pos2 = {
   div1: {
         left: 200
    },
   div2: {
         left: 400
    },
   div3: {
         left: 600
    }
};

alert(pos.div2.left);
//You could also make an array of objects for easier iteration
var pos3 = [
 {
     name: "div1",
     left: 200
 },{
     name: "div2",
     left: 400
 },{
     name: "div3",
     left: 600
 }
];

alert(pos3[2].name);
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/u9QXs/

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you asked is not looking like a `multi-dimensional` array,
But still you can achieve your need by changing your code like this

```
var pos= {'div1' :
               {'left' : 200},
          'div2' : 
               {'left' : 400}
          .
          .
          .
         };
```

and you can access it by,

```
 alert(pos.div1.left) //200
```